# Analytic solution to diffusion in composite medium for long times

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffusion

I am trying to find an analytical solution to the transient 1D diffusion equation in a composite medium (e.g. binary liquid):
$$\partial_t c_i = D\partial_x^2 c_i$$
where the domain for species $i$ is located from $-L \leq x \lt 0$ for species $1$ and $0\lt x\le L$ for species $2$. The interface is located at $x=0$ and has boundary conditions described by a concentration 'jump' and continuity of massflux respectively:
$$
c_1\left(0,t\right)=mc_2\left(0,t\right) \qquad D\frac{dc_1}{dx}\left(0,t\right)=-D\frac{dc_2}{dx}\left(0,t\right)
$$
For short times (i.e. $Fo=\frac{Dt}{L^2}\lt0.1$), a solution based on self-similarity is found if I assume the form:
$$c_i/c_0=1+A_i\exp(-\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\pi D t}})$$
which inherently contains the 'initial' and 'boundary' conditions:
$$c_1(0,x)=c_2(0,x)=c_0\quad c_1(t,-\infty)=c_2(t,\infty)=c_0$$
consistent with the self-similar nature where the mass has not diffused to the boundaries located at $x=\pm L$ yet.
The two coefficients $A_i$ are found using the interfacial boundary conditions.
This provides a closed set of solution of two equations for two unknowns.

For long times (i.e. $Fo\gg0.1$), the concentration profiles are no longer self-similar and the assumed form is no longer valid. Instead, I assume a general solution of the form:
$$
c_i=A_i+B_i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x}{L}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{Dt}{L^2}\right)
$$
Note that this solution is based on the solution for $Fo\gg0.1$ in a semi-infinite domain.
Analogous to the form for $Fo\ll0.1$, this general form implies that at the medium boundaries:
$$
\frac{dc_1}{dx}\left(-L,t\right)=\frac{dc_2}{dx}\left(L,t\right)=0
$$

However, this only provides 2 equations for 4 unknowns, requiring an additional two conditions for a closed set. Does anyone have any idea if this is solvable and if so, which extra conditions apply?

Comment: @Bzazz no it is intentional; for short times (i.e. $Fo\ll0.1$) the length scale $\sqrt{\pi Dt}$ is much smaller than the domain length scale $L$. It is therefor sufficient to say $c_i(t,\pm\infty)=c_0$. For long times, length scale is now comparable to the domain length scale.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realised later that it refers to something different, and I deleted the comment before seeing you had answered, apologies.

Comment: No problem, i have been struggling with this problem for a while and it is difficult to decide which details are (ir)relevant to understand the problem i'm having. So if anything is unclear, ask away!